# Can't trigger event click inside ng-template angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, primeng, splitter

I created two fieldsets, one is outside the ng-template and the other is inside of the splitter primeng components.

For the outside,the fieldset can be collapsed/expanded while those inside cannot. It's probably because I can't trigger event click inside the ng-template.

Pls find my code as below :
[text](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-splitter-demo-kubf56?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css&file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are querying the document for the `fieldset`, but you have two of those. Introduce `id` attribute to your fieldsets, then do the same thing for each fieldset.

Put `id`s to array: `indexes: string[] = ['fieldset1', 'fieldset2'];` and add to each `fieldset` their `id` attribute, like `<fieldset [id]="indexes[0]">` and `<fieldset [id]="indexes[1]">`, then change your `ngAfterViewInit()` method to iterate over `indexes` array, using each value for `getElementById` selector:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.indexes.forEach((id) => {

      const fieldset = document.getElementById(id);
      const content = fieldset.querySelector('.content');

      fieldset.querySelector('legend').addEventListener('click', function () {
        content.classList.toggle('hidden');
      });

      content.classList.remove('hidden');
    });
  }
```

Your edited [stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-splitter-demo-1k6ukn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).